# Manually setting Desktop vesion in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom Hook useWindowSize that determines whether there is a Mobile or Desktop environment. This is fine for most cases except when a mobile user wants to access the desktop version on his/her phone. I have a button to manually override the current windowsize but am not sure how to approach this.

Here I determine the opposite of the loaded windowsize but how can I switch and reload to the appropriate mode on click?

I will need this mode to stay afterwards even if the window is resized to keep the components linked to either mobile or desktop.

```
import "./styles.css";
import "./app.scss";
import useWindowSize from "./useWindowSize";

export default function App() {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  const otherMode = windowSize <= "useMobileVersion" ? "useDesktopVersion" : "useDesktopVersion";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Right now you are in {windowSize} mode. <button onClick={() => setPageMode("otherMode")}>
      Switch to {otherMode} mode
      </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The [codesandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-morning-ubzg2?file=/src/App.js).
The custom Hook is her:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

//a Util function that will convert the absolute width into breakpoints
function getBreakPoint(windowWidth) {
  if (windowWidth) {
    if (windowWidth < 420) {
      return "useMobileVersion";
    } else {
      return "useDesktopVersion";
    }
  } else {
    return "useDesktopVersion";
  }
}
function useWindowSize() {
  const isWindowClient = typeof window === "object";

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(
    isWindowClient ? getBreakPoint(window.innerWidth) : undefined
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    //a handler which will be called on change of the screen resize
    function setSize() {
      setWindowSize(getBreakPoint(window.innerWidth));
    }

    if (isWindowClient) {
      //register the window resize listener
      window.addEventListener("resize", setSize);

      //unregister the listener
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", setSize);
    }
  }, [isWindowClient, setWindowSize]);

  return windowSize;
}

export default useWindowSize;
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. What exactly are you trying to use the desktop version for? What are you setting manually that can't be done in css?

Comment: If a user chooses Desktop manually, they will be able to see the desktop version on their mobile device (and stay that way unless they choose manually to put it back to Mobile.

Comment: What does `setWindowSize` do?

Comment: It sets the window size if the wondow has changed size. [This is the original post](https://dev.to/3sanket3/usewindowsize-react-hook-to-handle-responsiveness-in-javascript-3dcl)